# Exception NoClassDefFoundError for CacheProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception, web-applications

I'm kind of new in Spring and hibernate so I'm trying to implement some simple web application based on Spring 3 + hibernate 4
while I start tomcat I have this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
```

I've found that this class was in hibernate-core for hibernate 3 but I've not found it in hibernate 4.

The part of my context.xml for persistence:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP_Address:SID"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.huawei.vms.user"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please help me to figure out why it's trying to load CacheProvider because I dont have any settings for that in context.xml and which jar I have to add in my project.
Thanks!

Comment: can you post the hibernate config file?

Comment: I don't have it. Maybe it is misunderstanding and I have to add that I did exactly what was described in book "Spring in action 3" chapter "5.4 Integrating Hibernate with Spring". While I was doing that I had some problems with absent classes that I found in hibernate, so I added hibernate 4 into my project. But it wasn't enouph

Comment: are you sure hibernate 4 has that class? I'd try hibernate 3.6.x

Comment: No. I've not found it in version 4. Actually, I have found it but in another package in ehcache. But the question is why tomcat trys to load it?  And is it actually needed?

Comment: It's deprecated from what I know

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Change your AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` (Hibernate 4) and you'll be good to go.  The AnnotationSessionFactoryBean was replaced with the LocalSessionFactoryBean as it does class path scanning now.

Comment: Any other possible ideas?  This does not seem to do anything for me.  Do the properties need to be changed?

Comment: Make sure you've changed the package from hibernate3 to hibernate4 - a LocalSessionFactoryBean exists in both packages.  What version of Spring and Hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 11):

This might be due to changes introduced in Hibernate 4 that are not compatible with Spring support for Hibernate.  This [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel) talks about adding separate package to support hibernate 4. You will need spring 3.1 for this. The other option is to stick to hibernate 3 if you don't need any specific feature introduced in 4.

Comment: Yes. I've downgrated from hiberante 4 to version 3.6.7 and everything became working. Thanks!

Comment: +1, got it working with both your and [Aaron's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8273320/56285) advice. (Or more precisely, got past this and run into other Hibernate 4 problems. :P) By the way, Spring 3.1 is no longer in RC (first GA release in December 2011).

Comment: thx @gkamal. Down-versioning to hibernate 3 worked for me. Solution: I used hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-core, both version 3.6.10.Final see http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=hibernate-entitymanager

Answer (score 8):

updating AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to hibernate4 works perfect. 
Also make sure your transactionManager also points to hibernate4,

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 <property name="packagesToScan" value="PACKAGE_NAME"></property>
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    </props>
 </property>    
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple problem that will cause the same error is simply to have a mismatch between the hibernate version in the pom (4.something) and the version specified in the spring config.