# Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4, SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

This was working:

```xml
<bean id="sessionFactory"  
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...
```

but upgrading to the aforementioned versions breaks it. What is the correct method to create a [*SessionFactory*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) bean with **Spring 3.1.Release** and **Hibernate 4.0.0.FINAL**?

The error on deploy is:

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;

**EDIT**
Have added my own answer, which fixed it for me.

Comment: Actually it's was deprecated. So removing is pretty suspectable http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider.html

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I think you should use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of 
`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

From `LocalSessionFactoryBean` javadoc:

> NOTE: This variant of LocalSessionFactoryBean requires Hibernate 4.0 or higher. It is similar in role to the same-named class in the orm.hibernate3 package. However, in practice, it is closer to AnnotationSessionFactoryBean since its core purpose is to bootstrap a SessionFactory from annotation scanning.

Comment: I can't see the orm.hibernate4 only the .hibernate3 could you give any insight here ? I have imported hibernate 4...
Solved: Make sure you use Spring 3.2.4 as well. 3.0.5 is too old.

Comment: I've just come across to this example, I hope this might help to anybody http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring

Answer (score 15):

Hibernate 4 has removed the deprecated `CacheProvider`-related interfaces and classes in favor of the previously released `RegionFactory`-related cache interface. You can find the version 4 cache package summary [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/package-summary.html), the version 3.2 cache package summary [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cache/package-summary.html) (just before the `RegionFactory` interface was added) and the version 3.3 cache package summary [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cache/package-summary.html) (when `RegionFactory` was first released).

Other than the JavaDoc, you might find the following documentation useful:

- [Using JBoss Cache as a Hibernate Second Level Cache - Chapter 5. Architecture](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/hibernate-caching/3.5/en-US/html/architecture.html)
- [Ehcache Hibernate Second-Level Cache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate)
- [Hibernate 4 - The Second Level Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache)

However, based on the Spring 3.1 [dependencies](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/dependencies?name=org.springframework.orm&version=3.1.0.RELEASE) Spring 3.1 does not require Hibernate 4 (under the `Full Dependencies` section, `JBoss Hibernate Object-Relational Mapper` is at version `3.3.2.GA`). If you want to upgrade to Hibernate 4, you'll need to update your cache settings. Otherwise, try using Hibernate 3.3.2 or higher 3.X version instead.

**UPDATE**: Keep in mind, Hibernate 4 documentation in Spring 3.1 is currently sparse. The `Spring Framework Reference Documentation` only has the following for [Support for Hibernate 4.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1385):

```
See Javadoc for classes within the new org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 package
```

Spring 3.1 introduces the [`LocalSessionFactoryBuilder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html), which extends Hibernate's [`Configuration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html).

It would seem you should keep an eye out for some [other changes](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel#issue-tabs) if you want to use Hibernate 4.

**UPDATE 2**: Just noticed this question is a close duplicate of [Exception NoClassDefFoundError for CacheProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider).

Answer (score 8):

Use this configuration

hibernate configuration file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

POM:

```
    <!-- CGLIB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        <!-- will come with Hibernate core -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

i forgot to include the versions, I am using hibernate version: 4.1.2.Final and spring version: 3.1.1.RELEASE, there is an update of hibernate 4.1.3.Final, not tested but I believe it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had to change a couple of things, here we go :

In my transaction manager set up changed 3 -> 4 :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
```

And my sessionFactory to this (thanks @toxin) :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
```

Comment: I did the same sir and got org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory' of bean class...

Answer (score 0):

- In the case of Hibernate 4.0 or higher, as of Spring 4.0, you should use

```java
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

For example:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html

- In the case of Hibernate 5.0/5.1/5.2, as of Spring 4.3, you should better instead use

```java
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

(See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

Answer (score -3):

Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4 are not compatible in so many ways. Please refer the following Spring JIRA https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9365

Comment: The report is about, Spring 3.x and Hibernate 4 are not compatible. Unable to use HibernateTemplate.
This is because HibernateTemplate is no longer supported by Hibernate 4.