# Spring MVC and Hibernate configurations

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. I am building a spring mvc hibernate framework.

I have the following configuration file

Please follow this link for the config file : [ConfigurationFile](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56970386/config.txt)

I am receiving the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Root cause:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Yes, I do have the spring-aop jar included in the class path. I would appreciate any help. My searches have not been fruitful.

---

Edit:

Thank you. That issue is solved, however my initial intention of this question was to solve the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

This is why I mentioned that I already have spring-aop in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` does not exist.

See the [Hibernate Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/package-frame.html).

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565051/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-sessionfactory).

> I think you should use
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean instead of 
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
>
> From LocalSessionFactoryBean javadoc:
>
> > NOTE: This variant of LocalSessionFactoryBean requires Hibernate 4.0 or higher. It is similar in role to the same-named class in the
> >     orm.hibernate3 package. However, in practice, it is closer to
> >     AnnotationSessionFactoryBean since its core purpose is to bootstrap a
> >     SessionFactory from annotation scanning.