# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myappname/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I have got error `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myappname/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'` when I was starting my project on JBoss. This is issue has occurred after resolving another issue described here: ["No Session found for current thread" after changing access method to the session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12299322/845220)

Before everything was working fine. I am using Apache Tiles 2. I am reading few similar questions but I can't find working solution.

This is my `DispatcherServlet Context` file without Hibernate configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="finances.webapp" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for resources by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</beans:bean>
```

My `web.xml` whole file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is my `IndexController`:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, Principal principal) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my configuration at this moment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` which is required to read the `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations. You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162459/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do).

Comment: Thnx ! This is what I missed !

Answer (score 0):

The solutio is to keep in `DispatcherServlet Context` file both `annotation-driven` tags like here:

```
<annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

I haven't found similar solution so I am gooing to leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your spring servlet.xml file

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

and

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
```

and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

In your controller class, use

```
 @Controller
 public class IndexController {..}
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exception and was trying all above solutions but nothing helped
but I did get a pointer the issue was because the class was not generated in the target class folder and it was due to incorrect Maven Project Structure which was leading to no compilation of Java controller class.

Check if you have below structure and then if class is generated in `target->class` folder then only try above suggestions.

```
Project
  src
    main
      java
      resources
    test
      java
      resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your .java file is under src/main/java instead src/main/resources