# After maven dependency update from spring 3.0 to 3.1.1 and hibernate 3.6 to 4.0 . Lots of error are coming

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

After 
I changes spring version from 3.0 to 3.1.1

and hibernate version from 3.6.filal to 4.1.7.Final

so I have to change
transaction manager class to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`

and session manager class to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

I tried various a lot but am not able to debug . . I have changed junit to 4.9 as some places I searched that this can also be a problem.

What can be the problem

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.32]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167) ~[org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) [org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) [org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
.
.
.
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.32]
```

==============================

## Updated after Solution

I have to remove

```
<property name="configurationClass">
 <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
```

from session factory definition

Comment: You run your tests on Tomcat? Check your scope for spring-test. Is it `test`? In that case it's not packed with your webapp

Comment: do you have a dependency on org.springframework:spring-test ?

Comment: @Reddy sir how will I be able to add Hibernate4 supported transaction manager

Comment: @radai yes org.springframework:spring-test is in dependence

Answer (score 1):

This will answer it

[Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4, SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565051/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-sessionfactory)

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

Comment: Thanks for the link I am looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Is the spring-test module/jar available on your project classpath?

Comment: Yes I have <dependency>   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>     <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Try removing the scope of the dependency.

Comment: Thanks solved my problem. .  scope was not the issue. . I have updated Question with solution.