# How to auto generate tables using Hibernate and MySQL using Java based configuration.

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Since I am not XML fan, I love to configure my applications using configuration classes.

I am working on simple web application using hibernate and MySQL I am trying to let hibernate create my tables but without any success.
As I googled around the way to do that is using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. My configuration bean looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class PersistenceConfigurations {



    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean factory(DataSource source) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(source);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);



        sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(
                Shit.class
        );

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setPort(3306);
        dataSource.setUser("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("passowrd");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("db_name");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

When I try to execute my test I get this error

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.tgallery.persistence.EntitiesAssociationSpikeTest.shouldReturnWhatWasSaved(EntitiesAssociationSpikeTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tgallery.Shit' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 49 more
```

I've already checked these questions and no answer is provided so please don't mark my question as duplicated as they don't use class based configs rather they use XML !

Comment: why do you want to do this? if you want to create and maintain database schema I would recommend  Liquibase or flyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` value to "`create`" for auto creation of tables from Annotated java classes

Comment: try using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation. AnnotationSessionFactoryBean  than LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: mm now this is something different ... I will try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241210/compatability-of-spring-4-0-0-with-hibernate-4-30 I cant use it because I am using Hibernate 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Change to `properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");`

or

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```