# Appfuse Tutorial troubles - BeanCreationException

Tags: appfuse

I'm working through the Appfuse tutorial for version 3.5 (as previously advised by Matt Raible in response to another question).

I'm on this step: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Spring+MVC#UsingSpringMVC-listview

But when I build (mvn package).. I get the following error:

Running gov.nysed.archives.Nimbus.dao.PersonDaoTest
Running gov.nysed.archives.Nimbus.webapp.controller.UpdatePasswordControllerTest

WARN [main] GenericApplicationContext.refresh(487) | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit h name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void gov.nysed.archives.Nimbus.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.set
MailMessage(org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage); nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE] ...

Could my adding the "persons" section (Entity and controller etc) cause this problem?  It passed the tests prior to adding the new entity... so of course, yes... but how?

Comment: It looks like you might have an older (or newer) version of Hibernate in your classpath. What version do you see when running "mvn dependency:tree | grep hibernate"?

Comment: appfuse-hibernate:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT
hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6
hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5
hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.6
hibernate-search:jar:4.5.1

Comment: This looks like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241210/compatability-of-spring-4-0-0-with-hibernate-4-30

Comment: This did help.  After updating to the correct hibernate, it got passed the error.  I then ran into other errors.  I needed to add a personController bean to the dispatcher-servlet.xml.  And then a personManager bean to applicationContext-service.xml.  And then move the personDao bean from applicationContext.xml to applicationContext-dao.xml.  Now, it passes tests.