# Could not autowire field is Spring MVC + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've started trying to get my head around spring mvc framework yesterday, and have encountered a problem. I get the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
Could not autowire field: com.springapp.mvc.service.UserService
com.springapp.mvc.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
```

I've checked other solutions and most of them have to do with people providing incorrect contexts. I've provided the base context, and not `.controller` directory. IntelliJ auto-generated me `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and I assume this is my application context. Does this mean I need to create servlet context?

Project structure:

[image: Structure]

I've ommited imports for a little more conciseness.

mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="vincas" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tieto"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springapp.mvc.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UserServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.service.impl;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public User getById(long id) {
        return userDao.getById(id);
    }

    public List<User> getByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return userDao.getByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public List<User> getByLastName(String lastName) {
        return userDao.getByLastName(lastName);
    }

    public List<User> getByFullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return userDao.getByFullName(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userDao.getAll();
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        userDao.delete(user);
    }
}
```

UserDaoImpl.java:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.dao.impl;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public User getById(long id) {
        return (User)getSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

    public List<User> getByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<User> getByLastName(String lastName) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<User> getByFullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        return null;
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        getSession().merge(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        getSession().delete(user);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

UserController.java:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String addUserGET(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "user/new";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUserPOST(Model model, @ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return new ModelAndView("user/success", "user", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241210/compatability-of-spring-4-0-0-with-hibernate-4-30

Comment: Could you try to add this <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> to your transaction manager bean.

Comment: Adding <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> did not have any effect.

Comment: Changing org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean made the server run finally.

Comment: Now, however, I am receiving error: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Comment: Not sure about the answer but you must enable the transaction support. Add <tx:annotation-driven> to your servlet.

Comment: @VincasStonys cool :)