# Upgraded to hibernate 4 and spring 4 jars but still getting org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to upgrade to `Hibernate 4.3.8` and `Spring 4.1.6`  version. When I am trying to initialize the context getting the exception as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:860) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

List of jars

> spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar,
>   spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-batch-core-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar,spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar,spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-oxm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-acl-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar,spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-config-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar,spring-ws-core-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar,spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar,spring-xml-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar,spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-taglibs-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar
>           hibernate-c3p0-4.3.8.Final.jar hibernate-envers-4.3.8.Final.jar
>           hibernate-search-engine-4.5.3.Final.jar
>           hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
>           hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
>           hibernate-search-orm-4.5.3.Final.jar hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar
>           hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.8.Final.jar
>           hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
>           hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.Final.jar  hibernate-search-4.5.3.Final.jar
>           hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar
>           hibernate-search-analyzers-4.5.3.Final.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compatability of spring 4.0.0 with hibernate 4.30](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241210/compatability-of-spring-4-0-0-with-hibernate-4-30)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your question**

1. You might be missing hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar in your classpath. It has FilterDefinition class.
2. Please add this dependency in your POM.xml file if you use Maven.

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: @ Gowtham, Please check if this exception still persists.

Comment: Still issue persists. I have added hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar and spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar  and in my property file org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean for sessionFactory and org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager for transaction manager.

Comment: @Gowtham, Please ensure you have **only** added the **SpringFramework 4.1.6 Bill of Materials (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.1.6.RELEASE.pom)** jar files in your classpath.

Comment: Yes I have added all the dependencies in my classpath.

Comment: @GowthamThurangi, Please add your configuration files in your question for better clarity. Also add your POM.xml (if you use) and list of dependent Jar files used in application.

Comment: <bean id="languageTranslatorTxManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="languageTranslatorSessionFactory" />
 </bean>

Comment: <bean id="abstractLanguageTranslatorSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" abstract="true"></bean> . I was not able to upload my configuration file.

Comment: You have to use LocalSessionFactoryBean to integrate with Hibernate and for transactions you to have use HibernateTransactionManager. This following link (http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring) will serve a good example