# Hibernate- Spring Intigration Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to Intigrate hibernate with spring.But facing below issue.

Logs:

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 20 more**

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>Emp.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value> 
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"/>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="com.infosys.bean.SessTemp">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>version</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>version</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

SessionTemplate.java

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class SessTemp {
    public HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public Employee getEmployeeById(int id)
    {
        Employee emp=(Employee) template.get(Employee.class, id);
        return emp;
    }

}
```

Please help me out!!

Comment: Try cleaning up your project and tomcat cache. If you are using STL, go to project -> settings -> deployment assembly and check if maven dependencies are there. Spring projects can be a pain in the ass with all those non-verbose errors. Could you add to your question the message `NoClassDefFoundError` provides?

Comment: I think this could be a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/25109098/1580304