# javax.servlet.jar and servlet-api.jar not loaded

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss

ı run project on tomcat 7(jdk8) with not problem in locale but it get follow error deploy war file with jboss 4.0.5.  does anybody idea? (ı am not using maven, update to hibernate 5.1 from hinernate 3 and spring framework 4.3.1)

```
2016-07-25 09:22:40,018 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader]       
validateJarFile(C:\...\...\server\default\.\deploy\ROOT.war\WEB
INF\lib\javax.servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section     
9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2016-07-25 09:22:40,053 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader]
validateJarFile(C:\...\server\default\.\deploy\ROOT.war\WEB-INF\lib\servlet- 
api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending 
class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2016-07-25 09:22:43,578 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
[jboss.web].[localhost].[/]] Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>  
(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:244)
at   
      org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setIntrospectionClass(BeanWrapperImpl.java:236)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.<init>(BeanWrapperImpl.java:130)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:717)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:733)
at com.liferay.portal.bean.BeanLocatorImpl.locate(BeanLocatorImpl.java:60)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorUtil.locate(BeanLocatorUtil.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalServiceFactory._getFactory(ReleaseLocalServiceFactory.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalServiceFactory.getService(ReleaseLocalServiceFactory.java:53)
at com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalServiceUtil.getBuildNumberOrCreate(ReleaseLocalServiceUtil.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:99)
at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessor._process(EventsProcessor.java:151)
at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessor.process(EventsProcessor.java:76)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:124)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:932)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3951)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5052)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:297)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:103)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:371)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at       
 org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at 
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    
org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1355)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1201)
... 198 more
```

Comment: jboss + tomcat + spring?

Comment: Take a look at the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241210/compatability-of-spring-4-0-0-with-hibernate-4-30

Comment: remove servlet-api.jar and javax.servlet.jar in \deploy\ROOT.war\WEB-INF\lib but ı get  'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition' error again. I made control in hibernateContext.xml follow; <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean>  ........correct as hibernate5

Comment: and another partial in hibernateContext.xml;

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> How can I fix?

Comment: Are you using JDK8 with JBOSS 4.0.5 ?

Comment: yes Nait, I am using them

Comment: local tomcat is using jdk8, jboss 4.0.5 is run win. server 2012 also, installed jdk 8 on server. there is defination JAVA_HOME path in run.bat

Comment: which jboss version can run with jdk1.8 correctly. http://wildfly.org/news/2014/11/20/WildFly82-Final-Released/ is enough?