# Hibernate4 & Lobhandler

Tags: spring, lob, hibernate-4.x

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider) i changed my session factory definition from

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:lobHandler-ref="oracleLobHandler">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        [..]
```

into

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        [..]
```

Unfortunately there is no possibility to define the LobHandler as it was in hibernate3. As there is still the following written in the "Lobhandler"s javadoc it seems still necessary

> Summarizing the recommended options (for actual LOB fields):
>
> - JDBC 4.0 driver: DefaultLobHandler with streamAsLob=true.
> - PostgreSQL: DefaultLobHandler with wrapAsLob=true.  Oracle 9i/10g:
> - OracleLobHandler with a connection-pool-specific NativeJdbcExtractor.
> - For all other database drivers (and for non-LOB fields that might potentially turn into LOBs on some databases): a plain
>     DefaultLobHandler.

So, is it still necessary to define the lobHandler in hibernate4 or not???
And if so, where can I define it?

Comment: As I couldn't find any sufficient answer to this I asked it on the springsource-forum right now http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?121103-hibernate4-SessionFactory-and-LOBHandler&p=396475#post396475

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't need it. They recommend using the native types as opposed to user types.

See http://www.sureshpw.com/2012/04/spring-hibernate-4.html.