# maven, hibernate, spring problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven

i have a problem with a project that i want to run with maven, in with i use spring and hibernate, i'm new to these technokogies by the way. just if someone can hepl me solve the problem, on post me an example which cab be runned easly , thnas you
this is my exception :

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)`

it's caused by :

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;`

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;`
....

thank you for help

Comment: There is a hibernate library missing. Which dependencies do you have defined in the POM?

Comment: Any closer to an answer?  In my pom file I have: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
```

Seems like you are missing [`hibernate-core.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.1.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar) in your project. Add it to your CLASSPATH. [Pick version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/) that is compatible with the rest of your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of posts on the same issue. You can check below links and if that doesnt solve your problem then can put the configuration xml file you use to integrate spring with hibernate.

[Exception NoClassDefFoundError for CacheProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider)

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider exception while integrating spring and hiberate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978094/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-cache-cacheprovider-exception-wh)