# Eror while creating bean on hibernate spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring and hibernate on this project I'm using netbeans v.8.2 and I'm using library spring 3.2.7 and hibernate 4.3.x
what should I do to fix the error ?

The eror:
Error creating bean with name 'dao' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider

this is the application context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kampus"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value=""></property>  
</bean>  
  
<bean id="mysessionFactory"  
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
      
    <property name="mappingResources">  
    <list>  
    <value>Mahasiswa.hbm.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  
      
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
              
        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>  
  
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
</bean>  
  
<bean id="dao" class="dao.MahasiswaDao">  
<property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>  
  
  
</beans>
```

this is mahasiswa.java (mahasiswa=student in English):

```
package entity;

public class Mahasiswa  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private String npm;
 private String nama;
 private String jurusan;
 private String alamat;

public Mahasiswa() {
}

public Mahasiswa(String npm, String nama, String jurusan, String alamat) {
   this.npm = npm;
   this.nama = nama;
   this.jurusan = jurusan;
   this.alamat = alamat;
}

public String getNpm() {
    return this.npm;
}

public void setNpm(String npm) {
    this.npm = npm;
}
public String getNama() {
    return this.nama;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
    this.nama = nama;
}
public String getJurusan() {
    return this.jurusan;
}

public void setJurusan(String jurusan) {
    this.jurusan = jurusan;
}
public String getAlamat() {
    return this.alamat;
}

public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    this.alamat = alamat;
}


}
```

This is Mahasiswa.dao :

```
package dao;
import entity.Mahasiswa;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
public class MahasiswaDao {
HibernateTemplate template;
public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
this.template = template;  
}
public void saveMahasiswa(Mahasiswa m){
    template.save(m);
}
}
```

this is mahasiswa.hbm.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 30, 2021 6:57:57 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entity.Mahasiswa" table="mahasiswa" catalog="kampus" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="npm" type="string">
        <column name="npm" length="13" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="nama" type="string">
        <column name="nama" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="jurusan" type="string">
        <column name="jurusan" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="alamat" type="string">
        <column name="alamat" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is the main.java :

```
public class test06 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  
  
MahasiswaDao dao=(MahasiswaDao)factory.getBean("dao");  
  
Mahasiswa m=new Mahasiswa();  
m.setNpm("1");  
m.setNama("test");  
m.setJurusan("");
m.setAlamat("");
  
dao.saveMahasiswa(m); 
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `org.hibernate.cache.Provider` class on the `classpath`.

As per [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider exception while integrating spring and hiberate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978094/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-cache-cacheprovider-exception-wh)

> *org.hibernate.cache.Provider was removed in the change from
> Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4*.

You're using Hibernate 4, but the Hibernate-related classes from Spring you're using in `applicationContext.xml` are from `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` package, so they need that missing dependency.

Try using the HibernateTemplate and LocalSessionFactoryBean from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package.

If there isn't such a package in Spring 3.2.7, upgrade to Spring 4.

Comment: thanks for your reply man.. but i get the new error, I try to search and fix it but i cant maybe u can lend me some help
the error : Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.

Comment: i fix the new error with template.setCheckWriteOperations(false); on method saveMahasiswa on class MahasiswaDao and it works fine.. 
but the data that I try to save on main method it's not inserted into the database.
Does anyone knows why ?? because I'm still new on this spring and hibernate