# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 maven or jar download

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration, web

I was getting error like this in my hibernate, spring web project configuration:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:3
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcesso
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBean
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        ... 48 more
```

My hibernate and spring dependencies at pom.xml are as follows :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I was using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean being used in my configuration.

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

According to  suggestion from  [a wikipage @ googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/jgk-spring-recipes/wiki/Migrating_Spring31_Hibernate4) :
 and [Exception NoClassDefFoundError for CacheProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider),  I decided to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of  `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

But, I couldn't locate `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4`. I already searched at http://mvnrepository.com . Could you please help me?

Is there other solution to avoid "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider`" error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 3.0 does not support Hibernate 4. Support for Hibernate 4 was added to Spring 3.1, so if you wish to use Hibernate 4 then you must migrate your Spring version up. Yes, I know this may be a non-trivial proposition; I'm currently sticking with Spring 3.0 in my code because of versioning problems. Your alternatives are to not use Hibernate 4 and stick with 3, or to do all the glue layer yourself rather than using the code predefined in Spring.

---

Diagnosis: `org.hibernate.cache.Provider` was removed in the change from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4 — [JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider) doesn't find it in any non-3 JAR that I believe to be a genuine just-hibernate article — so Spring 3.0 will *not* work with Hibernate 4. (Hey, it's a major version number change so they *are* allowed to do that.)

Prognosis: Upgrade Spring, downgrade Hibernate, or DIY.

Comment: thanks. i upgraded spring  to "3.1.1.RELEASE" version and it worked. ... and thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

i am using spring 3.1.0-release and hibernate-4.0.0-final
i had the same problem too, i change the session factory to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

and the transaction manager to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager
```

also an open session in view filter to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor
```

and then it works,my suggestion is looking for '.hibernate3.' in you spring config and replace it with hibernate 4 related class

Good luck!