# org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/resources/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:544)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
    ... 19 more
```

List of jars:

- hibernate3.jar
- hibernate-core-4.1.2.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-testing.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar

They are all in my project class path. Are these versions not compatible with the configurations?

applicationcontext.xml has following code :

`<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">`

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769026/org-springframework-orm-hibernate4-maven-or-jar-download

Comment: thanks.this was helpful to overcome the bug.

Comment: If you found your problem post your own answer and choose it so the question is classed as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded spring to 3.1.1 release.then problem was solved.