# Spring MVC template project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-tool-suite

I am following the tutorial http://krams915.blogspot.ie/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html

I am having trouble when I enter localhost:8080/tutorial/krams/main/persons to the URL bar. I keep getting 404 errors. My top level package is org.krams.tutorial and I have set the name of the project to tutorial.

(I am using the Spring MVC template in STS. I deleted Home Controller.java and home.jsp. I am not sure if this is having an effect. The directory structure for the Spring MVC template is different to the Krams tutorial. When I download Krams project and run it in STS it works fine, but I wanted to do it myself from scratch). Hopefully someone can help me! Its very frustrating!
Here is my code.

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.tutorial" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.tutorial" />



</beans:beans>
```

**hibernate-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="org.krams.tutorial"/>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="5"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="100"
                p:maxStatements="50"
                p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
            Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**spring.properties**

```
# database properties
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=nbuser

#hibernate properties
hibernate.config=/WEB-INF/spring/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

**MainController.java**

```
package org.krams.tutorial.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.krams.tutorial.domain.Person;
import org.krams.tutorial.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


/**
 * Handles and retrieves person request
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("krams/main")
public class MainController {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    @Resource(name="personService")
    private PersonService personService;

    /**
     * Handles and retrieves all persons and show it in a JSP page
     * 
     * @return the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersons(Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to show all persons");

        // Retrieve all persons by delegating the call to PersonService
        List<Person> persons = personService.getAll();

        // Attach persons to the Model
        model.addAttribute("persons", persons);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/personspage.jsp
        return "personspage";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the add page
     * 
     * @return the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAdd(Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show add page");

        // Create new Person and add to model
        // This is the formBackingOBject
        model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new Person());

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addpage.jsp
        return "addpage";
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new person by delegating the processing to PersonService.
     * Displays a confirmation JSP page
     * 
     * @return  the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("personAttribute") Person person) {
        logger.debug("Received request to add new person");

        // The "personAttribute" model has been passed to the controller from the JSP
        // We use the name "personAttribute" because the JSP uses that name

        // Call PersonService to do the actual adding
        personService.add(person);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addedpage.jsp
        return "addedpage";
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing person by delegating the processing to PersonService.
     * Displays a confirmation JSP page
     * 
     * @return  the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delete(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Integer id, 
                                            Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to delete existing person");

        // Call PersonService to do the actual deleting
        personService.delete(id);

        // Add id reference to Model
        model.addAttribute("id", id);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/deletedpage.jsp
        return "deletedpage";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the edit page
     * 
     * @return the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEdit(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Integer id,  
                                            Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show edit page");

        // Retrieve existing Person and add to model
        // This is the formBackingOBject
        model.addAttribute("personAttribute", personService.get(id));

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/editpage.jsp
        return "editpage";
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing person by delegating the processing to PersonService.
     * Displays a confirmation JSP page
     * 
     * @return  the name of the JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEdit(@ModelAttribute("personAttribute") Person person, 
                                               @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Integer id, 
                                                    Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to update person");

        // The "personAttribute" model has been passed to the controller from the JSP
        // We use the name "personAttribute" because the JSP uses that name

        // We manually assign the id because we disabled it in the JSP page
        // When a field is disabled it will not be included in the ModelAttribute
        person.setId(id);

        // Delegate to PersonService for editing
        personService.edit(person);

        // Add id reference to Model
        model.addAttribute("id", id);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/editedpage.jsp
        return "editedpage";
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Two questions does the logger print anything out indicating that you have hit the method and could you post your web.xml file?

Comment: I have posted the logger print at http://www.jamesanthony527.com

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your logs I can see that you get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider

A quick look over at Google resulted in a SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider) that states the issue is with the hibernate version you might be using in combination with spring. Editing your hibernate-context.xml with the suggested Factory might resolve your issue.