# integration of spring 3, hibernate 3, maven and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I tried different sessionFactory in applicationContext.xml. it has the same problem.
any advice would be appreciate in advanced!
applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.peterhuang.myweb" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.peterhuang.myweb" />
    <property name="annotatedPackages" value="org.peterhuang.myweb" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${jdbc.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                ${hibernate.show_sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                ${hibernate.format_sql}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

here is the pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.peterhuang</groupId>
<artifactId>myweb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myweb Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>

    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsp standard tag lib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- tomcat -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- jdbc mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>myweb</finalName>
</build>
```

here is the error track. I'm running it within eclipse, on tomcat 7 server

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
```

CategoryDAOImpl

```
package org.peterhuang.myweb.dao.impl;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.peterhuang.myweb.dao.CategoryDAO;
import org.peterhuang.myweb.model.Category;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository(value = "categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (List<Category>) sessionFactory.openSession()
            .getNamedQuery("findAllCategory").list();
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
}
```

CategoryDAO

```
package org.peterhuang.myweb.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.peterhuang.myweb.model.*;

@Service
public interface CategoryDAO {

public List<Category> getCategoryList();

}
```

Category.java

```
package org.peterhuang.myweb.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "findAllCategory", query = "from CATEGORY s ") })
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

@Id
@Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME")
private String categoryName;

public Category() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
}
```

PageController.java

```
package org.peterhuang.myweb.web;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.peterhuang.myweb.dao.impl.CategoryDAOImpl;
import org.peterhuang.myweb.model.Category;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class PageController {

@Resource
private CategoryDAOImpl categoryDAOImpl;

@RequestMapping(value = "/mainpage")
public String mainPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    List<Category> categoryList = categoryDAOImpl.getCategoryList();
    System.out.println(categoryList);

    session.setAttribute("categoryList", categoryList);
    return "mainpage";
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>my web</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Can you run a `mvn dependency:tree`? Let's make sure the versions of dependencies are as you expect them to be.

Comment: I run mvn test. it build sucess

Comment: That isn't what I said, but regardless @Sotirios found the dependency issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have JAR hell situation.

For whatever reason, this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

which has a `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` class is hiding the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` class, ie. same name, in this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And that class doesn't have a `setPackagesToScan` method. Get rid of the `spring-hibernate3` dependency. `spring-orm` should be more than enough. You can download the source [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/2.0.8/spring-2.0.8-sources.jar) and check for yourself.

Comment: I did what you said. error changed to org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;

Comment: @user2788424 That's because that class was removed in Hibernate 4. You should be using `LocalSessionFactoryBean` as others have noted.

Comment: @user2788424 See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider

Comment: @user2788424 You are welcome. Consider upvoting answers that helped you and accepting answers that were most useful.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that the property `packagesToScan` takes up a `String array` rather than a simple `String`. Try changing the property from:

`<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.peterhuang.myweb" />`

to

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>org.peterhuang.myweb</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: That you will have to test.

Comment: Spring uses a conversion service for this. There is no problem putting the values directly.

Comment: Ohh. I didn't know that. Maybe the OP can just try it out. Let's see if it works.

Comment: My point is it won't change anything. OP even says it in their comment.