# bean for using sessionFactory in multiple classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am doing [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/), but I had to upgrade to Hibernate 4 among other small adjustments.  As a result, I had to use sessionFactory in a second class file, rather than just using it in the single class file used in the tutorial.  The use of sessionFactory is causing the following error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'documentController':  
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Could not autowire field:  
private net.viralpatel.docmanager.dao.DocumentDAO net.viralpatel.docmanager.controller.DocumentController.documentDao;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'documentDAO':  
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.docmanager.dao.DocumentDAO.sessionFactory;  
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
```

How can I change my code to fix this problem?  I will enclose the bean, and the two class files that are now calling sessionFactory.

Here is the bean definision from spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the DocumentDAO class, which uses sessionFactory:

```
@Repository
public class DocumentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Document document) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(document);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Document> list() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Document> documents = null;
        try {documents = (List<Document>)session.createQuery("from Document").list();} 
        catch (HibernateException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return documents;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Document get(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (Document)session.get(Document.class, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remove(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Document document = (Document)session.get(Document.class, id);
        session.delete(document);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for DocumentController, to which I had to add sessionFactory as part of the upgrade to Hibernate 4:

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDAO documentDao;
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
        try {
            map.put("document", new Document());
            map.put("documentList", documentDao.list());
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return "documents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("document") Document document, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Name:" + document.getName());
        System.out.println("Desc:" + document.getDescription());
        System.out.println("File:" + file.getName());
        System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

        try {
            Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
            document.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            document.setContent(blob);
            document.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try {documentDao.save(document);} 
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/download/{documentId}")
    public String download(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Document doc = documentDao.get(documentId);
        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +doc.getFileName()+ "\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
            IOUtils.copy(doc.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{documentId}")
    public String remove(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId) {
        documentDao.remove(documentId);
        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT/ANSWER:

To solve this problem, I needed to make the following changes:

```
Change Hibernate3 to Hibernate4 in the sessionFactory AND transactionManager beans  
Remove the configLocation and configurationClass properties from sessionFactory bean  
Add packagestoscan property to sessionFactory bean  
Add a list of values within the annotatedclasses property of the sessionFactory bean
Keep other things the same
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well quoting another answer :

> Change your AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean (Hibernate 4) and you'll be good to go. The AnnotationSessionFactoryBean was replaced with the LocalSessionFactoryBean as it does class path scanning now.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273320/1173560)

Something like:

```
    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com...</value>
                all the annotated classes come here
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: The error says : Bean property 'configurationClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

Just remove that property and try again. :)

Comment: I figured out the answer and posted it in an edit to my original posting above.  The last missing detail was changing transactionManager to hibernate4 from 3.  Your help got me in the right direction.  So +1 and credit for the answer.  Thank you.