# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, classnotfoundexception, sessionfactory

I'm trying to run my web app using Tomcat and totally confused because of this exception. Here is a stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 40 more
```

The part of my data.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softserve.edu.entity" />
    <property name="configurationClass"><value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hibernate dependency is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528862/exception-noclassdeffounderror-for-cacheprovider) question seems like has to work, but it doesn't. Will be appreciate for some useful tips.

Comment: Are you also using spring?

Comment: Well, this class indeed doesn't exist in Hibernate 4.3: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/. Do you use it in your own code? Or is it used by a library you're also using?

Answer (score -1):

add this in your XML

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```